# Achievement link takes me to the wrong page

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

An achievement URL for `+2 RAID configuration on new server` which is supposed to take me to [RAID configuration on new server](https://serverfault.com/questions/1142529/raid-configuration-on-new-server) instead takes me to the URL [Android: How do a display a large animated gif given a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809878/android-how-do-a-display-a-large-animated-gif-given-a-url/1142529#1142529)

The immediate surrounding HTML looks correct:

```
<a href="/questions/1142529/raid-configuration-on-new-server" class="js-gps-track d-flex gs8 gsx" data-gps-track="site.switch({ target_site:2, item_type:6 });" achievements_popup.click({="" item_type:4})="" aria-label="2 reputation change: RAID configuration on new server, earned on Server Fault, 16 hours ago">
    <div class="favicon favicon-serverfault site-icon flex--item" title="Server Fault"></div>
    <span class="js-faux-column rep-change js-rep-change rep-up flex--item" title="16 hours ago" style="width: 30px;">
        +2
    </span>
    <div class="message-text flex--item fl1">
        <h4 class="">RAID configuration on new server</h4>
    </div>
</a>
```

The full `document.documentElement.outerHTML` can be obtained by running:

```
wget 'http://paste.debian.net/plain/1290462' -O- | base64 -d | xz -d > html.html
```

I tried posting the full HTML raw, but it was so big that my web browser started freezing when I tried making this post. Then I tried posting the html.xz.base64 directly in this post, but I got the error: *Body is limited to 50000 characters; you entered 67550.*

Here is a video recording: https://imgur.com/a/5gOIpBZ

Comment: This was fixed today - see the answer to the duplicate.